# Monotonicity of sum of exponential functions

Tags: monotone-functions

Let $f(x)=2^x+5^x-7^x$. The problem is to study the monotonicity intervals of $f(x)$.

My first attempt to tackle the above, is to study the sign of the derivative of $f(x)$

$f^\prime (x)=ln(2)\cdot 2^x+ln(5)\cdot5^x-ln(7)\cdot7^x$

However I can see no obvious way of proceeding. Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: i think $f(x)$ isn't monoton

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The question is (I believe) about finding those intervals in which $f(x)$ __is__ monotone. It's not monotone on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner it is not monotone. That's why the problem refers intervals of monotonicity

Comment: You cannot find critical points exactly. You could try to locate then numerically...